# Monitor Bonded Interface for Disconnection

Tags: linux, networking, bonding

I am trying to monitor for network failures on a machine, and one portion of that is to monitor interfaces that are intended to be active also be "RUNNING".

An Ethernet port, such as `eth0`, will say "RUNNING" if it is physically connected to another device.

The problem lies in the bonded interfaces, such as `bond0`. If all of the ethernet devices are disconnected, it still says that it is running, and it is still pingable. Is this by design, or is my system setup incorrectly? Does the `miimon` option have something to do with this?

---

**EDIT**

I found a possible issue, thanks to Gregor. When I ran `cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0`, it gave me this (notice **MII Polling Interval**):

```
Bonding Mode: load balancing (round-robin)
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 0
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0

Slave Interface: eth7
MII Status: up
Link Failure Count: 0
```

But in my /etc/modprobe.conf, I set it up like this:

```
alias bond0 bonding
options bond0 -o bond0 mode=0 miimon=100
```

So, evidently, the miimon setting is not working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script could scan /proc/net/bonding/bondX for some status information.
- Greg

Comment: Ah, found a possible problem. I will edit the main post with updated info.

Comment: Well, what do you know, rebooting fixed it. I don't think I did anything to change it, but maybe I did.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at `ethtool` or `mii-tool`?  That's typically how I determine link status without physically inspecting the server in Linux.

Comment: Well, that's a better way to do it, but it has the same issue. It says the link is up, but no slaved devices are connected. See my edit above.